# errors while launching amazon ec2 t2.micro instance from windows command prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, ec2-ami

I am a new user for amazon ec2 services.
I created a linux instance and with the help of ssh keys generated I was able to ssh into instance using putty on a Windows 7 machine.
I read documentation given on following link under section 
"launch and connect to instances"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html
based on this I am running following command on windows command prompt.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name “datastructutrekey” --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' " i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
```

but I am getting errros

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operatio
n: Invalid value 'A¢A?A?datastructutrekeyA¢A?A?' for keyPairNames. Text is not i
n valid ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1) encoding

D:\folder where aws keys are>" i-03e7f6391a
0f523ee"
'" i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can any one point out what mistake I am doing and how do I fix this?

when I tried to run the command as follows

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name “datastructutre key” --query ''Instances[0].InstanceId'' "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
```

I get following error

```
Bad value for --query ''Instances[0].InstanceId'': Unexpected token: Instances:
Parse error at column 2, token "Instances" (UNQUOTED_IDENTIFIER), for expression
:
"''Instances[0].InstanceId''"
   ^
```

which command above is more appropriate and how can I fix the errors above?
Additionally I am posting the output of

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

so that it may give you a better idea

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "ImageId": "ami-d783a9b8",
                    "InstanceId": "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                    "KeyName": "datastructutre key",
                    "LaunchTime": "2018-08-01T04:28:52.000Z",
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "Placement": {
                        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "Tenancy": "default"
                    },
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.20.16",
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    "PublicDnsName": "",
                    "State": {
                        "Code": 80,
                        "Name": "stopped"
                    },
                    "StateTransitionReason": "",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-d3fdbabb",
                    "VpcId": "vpc-08356c60",
                    "Architecture": "x86_64",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "AttachTime": "2018-08-01T04:28:52.000Z",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "VolumeId": "vol-09716d3308f44c63f"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "",
                    "EbsOptimized": false,
                    "EnaSupport": true,
                    "Hypervisor": "xen",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Attachment": {
                                "AttachTime": "2018-08-01T04:28:52.000Z",
                                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-08d060230b617ca70",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                                "Status": "attached"
                            },
                            "Description": "",
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58"
                                }
                            ],
                            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                            "MacAddress": "02:5a:17:52:69:a6",
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0146aab6d9503bf47",
                            "OwnerId": "1****************",
                            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.20.16",
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "Primary": true,
                                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.20.16"
                                }
                            ],
                            "SourceDestCheck": true,
                            "Status": "in-use",
                            "SubnetId": "subnet-d3fdbabb",
                            "VpcId": "vpc-08356c60"
                        }
                    ],
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                    "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                            "GroupId": "sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": true,
                    "StateReason": {
                        "Code": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown",
                        "Message": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown"
                    },
                    "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
                    "CpuOptions": {
                        "CoreCount": 1,
                        "ThreadsPerCore": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "1xxxxxxxx",
            "ReservationId": "r-xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

also C:\Users>aws --version

```
aws-cli/1.15.80 Python/3.7.0 Windows/7 botocore/1.10.79
```

**answer**
There were mistakes in way double quotes were coming by copy pasting commands.
What I wanted was start-instance instead I was doing aws ec2 run-instances 
following command launched an existing instance 
`C:\Users>aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-03e7f6391a0f523ee`

it launched the instance but to connect to it via putty I had to look the IP address which was changed when instance state changed from stopped to running after many days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what keyboard or language settings you are using ...

For your first command you have entered some strange quote marks that are not standard quote marks. Edit your command and replace those with normal ones. Next this same command is specifying an instance id at the end " i-03e7f6391a0f523ee". Remove this. For your question you are specifying the Key Pair name differently. Figure out the correct name and use that one.

For your second command, you are again using strange syntax for quotation marks. Here you are using two single quotes instead of one quotation mark. You also have that instance ID on the end. Remove that.

Your AWS CLI version is fine.

Comment: how to find out key pair name I downloaded the keypair with datastructurekey.pem file as far as I remember the name while creating on web had a blank space datastructure key , I am using double quotes to because of spaces in name.Is that not the correct thing because in linux we usually can use backslash to omit the space in filename in windows I don't know. This is a normal QWERTY keyboard with EN-US default language.

Comment: The laptop model is Dell Inspiron 1545.

Comment: The filename of your key pair is not the Key Pair Name. Go to the AWS console -> EC2 -> Key Pairs and look up the name. Or use the CLI "aws ec2 describe-key-pairs". You can use a double quote mark (not two single quotes) around names that have spaces. The same for Windows and Linux. I think you are confusing escaping quote marks with using quote marks. Remember, don't copy and paste commands from articles. Some use charsets that are not ASCII.

Comment: here is the output from `C:>aws ec2 describe-key-pairs`  
`{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyFingerprint": "c0:69:23:f4:0c:14:5b:",
            "KeyName": "datastructutre key"
        }
    ]
}`

the double quotes are besides the enter key I press `shift + '` to get the double quotes is that key combination not right to use here.

Comment: Your key pair name is "datastructutre key". This means surround thetwo words with a quote mark. Yes you are referencing the correct quote mark to use. In your question you are not using the correct quote mark in several places.

Comment: following command worked `C:\Users\DEEL>aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d
3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name "datastructutre key" --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId'
"Instances[0].InstanceId"`

but rather than bringing a stopped instance to running condition it created a new instance with a different instance id than the one which I wanted to poweron, I checked in aws ec2 console on web.

Comment: run-instance "creates" a new instance. start-instance "starts" an existing instance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html

Comment: I have terminated the instance which was created due to use of run-instance is there a way it can get permanently deleted from aws console also. It is showing me when I login to console.aws.com I am new user so don't want to confuse myself with lot of instances.

Comment: Terminating an instance is not "instant". Wait five minutes. Refresh the AWS console. If the instance is still there, terminate it in the console.

Comment: Select one of the answers and close this question. If you have new questions, create another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name “datastructutrekey” --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId'
```

Has 'curly quotes' around `datastructutrekey`, possibly caused by copying text from a word processor (eg Microsoft Word).

Replace them with straight quotes:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name "datastructutrekey" --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId'
```

Comment: you pointed right I was copy pasting the command from microsoft word file I copy pasted the line you mentioned above. then I get following error 
`C:\Users\>aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d783a9b8 --subnet-id subnet-d
3fdbabb --security-group-ids sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58 --count 1 --instance-type t2.m
icro --key-name "datastructutrekey" --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId'

An error occurred (InvalidKeyPair.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances operat
ion: The key pair 'datastructutrekey' does not exist`

Comment: That's because the Keypair doesn't exist. In the EC2 management console, click **Key Pairs** in the left navigation pane. Use the name of the keypair as it is displayed in the list. I think you have a typo in `datastructutrekey`

Comment: yes you figured out correct there was a typing mistake , I have updated the question with answer

Answer (score 0):

How to connect to AWS Linux instance from your laptop using PuTTy

1. Launch EC2 instance
2. I selected Red Hat Linux AMI to install Linux image.
3. Created new Key Pair .pem file.
4. Install Putty in my Laptop.
5. Run PuTTyGen and click on Load
6. Change to select All Files (*.*).
7. Then Select .pem file
8. Then Click on Save private key
9. And give any name for this new key pair.
10. Now you can connect your instance using putty
11. Copy and paste public ip of your linux instance
12. Next expand SSH and click on Auth.
13. Click on Browse and select you new key pair from location you saved it, click on open
14. If you want to save this go on the top in category on left, and click on session
15. Type the name under saved session and click on save.
16. Now you can open your session, give ec2-user and press enter
    You are now connected.